PostgreSQL "create foreign table" (file_fdw) on files with single quotes in filename generates ERROR
I have a CSV file with a silly filename (for example): 'test_1111 _2_ABC Hr. Schmidt_2024.csv'
postgres@minisforum:~/16/import$ ll
insgesamt 1212
drwxrwxr-x 3 postgres postgres    4096 Okt 14 19:16  ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 postgres postgres    4096 Okt 13 15:41  ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 postgres postgres 1228581 Okt 14 19:14 'test_1111 _2_ABC Hr. Schmidt_2024.csv'

After some tries I can create a foreign table on this file:
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_fdw( datum text, pr integer, standort text, ... ) 
SERVER fdw_files OPTIONS (filename '/var/lib/postgresql/16/import/''test_1111 _2_ABC Hr. Schmidt_2024.csv''', format 'csv', header 'true', delimiter ';');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE

With other combinations I get an error on CREATE.
With \det+ you get:
Liste der Fremdtabellen
  Schema  |     Tabelle      |  Server   |                                                                     FDW-Optionen                                                                      | Beschreibung
----------+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------
 abc      | test_fdw         | fdw_files | (filename '/var/lib/postgresql/16/import/''test_1111 _2_ABC Hr. Schmidt_2024.csv''', format 'csv', header 'true', delimiter ';')                      |

A correctly declared foreign table! But I have no access on this table:
postgres=# select * from test_fdw;
FEHLER:  konnte Datei »/var/lib/postgresql/16/import/'test_1111 _2_ABC Hr. Schmidt_2024.csv'« nicht zum Lesen öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
TIP:  Mit COPY FROM liest der PostgreSQL-Serverprozess eine Datei. Möglicherweise möchten Sie Funktionalität auf Client-Seite verwenden, wie zum Beispiel \copy in psql.

File or Directory was not found. This is not a file permission problem. Also no success with the COPY command. Does anybody have a hint for me? Did I found a bug in file_fdw?

ls -l behind the ll alias is adding the single quotes because the file name has spaces in it, not because the name really starts and ends with single quotes. I suppose the errors you got before were unrelated to whether or not the file exists - it would help if you showed those attempts and errors too.

Yes, you are right! ll and ls show me quotes, but ls -N does not. I created the foreign table without the double quotes and it works. Unforetunately I get another error with UTF8 coding during select, but this is another case. Thank you!

demo at db<>fiddle
create extension if not exists file_fdw;
CREATE SERVER fdw_files FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;

copy(select 'datum1' as datum
          , 1 as pr 
          , 'standort1' as standort
)to'/tmp/test_1111 _2_ABC Hr. Schmidt_2024.csv'
with(  format 'csv'
     , header true
     , delimiter ';');

The create foreign table works regardless of whether the file exists at the time. Neither its existence nor structure is validated until you attempt a read from it:
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
  test_fdw(  datum text
           , pr integer
           , standort text ) 
SERVER fdw_files 
OPTIONS(  filename '/tmp/''test_1111 _2_ABC Hr. Schmidt_2024.csv'''
        , format 'csv'
        , header 'true'
        , delimiter ';');

The above works fine, then fails at the first read. ls -l behind the ll alias is adding the single quotes because the file name has spaces in it, not because the name really starts and ends with single quotes, so forcing them in there results in a mismatched file name.
select*from test_fdw;


ERROR:  could not open file "/tmp/'test_1111 _2_ABC Hr. Schmidt_2024.csv'" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.


As immediately pointed out by @Laurenz Albe, it should be enough to just not force the single quotes ll used for wrapping, into the file name - as a SQL string constant it's already wrapped along with the rest of the path
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
  test_fdw(  datum text
           , pr integer
           , standort text ) 
SERVER fdw_files 
OPTIONS(  filename '/tmp/test_1111 _2_ABC Hr. Schmidt_2024.csv'
        , format 'csv'
        , header 'true'
        , delimiter ';');

select*from test_fdw;




datum
pr
standort




datum1
1
standort1




ls -N show me the file without quotes, creating the foreign table without double quotes works!

You defined the file name to contain single quotes, but it doesn't. Use
OPTIONS (
   filename '/var/lib/postgresql/16/import/test_1111 _2_ABC Hr. Schmidt_2024.csv',
   format 'csv',
   header 'true',
   delimiter ';'
)

